# IPN Post data, submissions from IPN simulator and from actual purchases contain different key names

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I originally thought that my IPN script wasn't receiving any post data at all when being sent from a transaction generated by a sandbox user, but the data is actually there, the array just has different key names for each variable compared to the IPN simulator. I searched on Google but wasn't really able to find anyone having the same issue or a resolution for it.

I noticed in the post data from the user transaction that it has a "Version" variable that isn't set, do you think the IPN simulator is using a later version that is giving the keys different names?

Has anyone come across this before or perhaps can shed some light as to whats causing this?

This is the post data from the IPN simulator:

```
  ["test_ipn"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["payment_type"]=>
  string(7) "instant"
  ["payment_date"]=>
  string(25) "22:58:32 Feb 13, 2013 PST"
  ["payment_status"]=>
  string(9) "Completed"
  ["address_status"]=>
  string(9) "confirmed"
  ["payer_status"]=>
  string(8) "verified"
  ["first_name"]=>
  string(4) "John"
  ["last_name"]=>
  string(5) "Smith"
  ["payer_email"]=>
  string(23) "buyer@paypalsandbox.com"
  ["payer_id"]=>
  string(13) "TESTBUYERID01"
  ["address_name"]=>
  string(10) "John Smith"
  ["address_country"]=>
  string(13) "United States"
  ["address_country_code"]=>
  string(2) "US"
  ["address_zip"]=>
  string(5) "95131"
  ["address_state"]=>
  string(2) "CA"
  ["address_city"]=>
  string(8) "San Jose"
  ["address_street"]=>
  string(15) "123, any street"
  ["business"]=>
  string(24) "seller@paypalsandbox.com"
  ["receiver_email"]=>
  string(24) "seller@paypalsandbox.com"
  ["receiver_id"]=>
  string(13) "TESTSELLERID1"
  ["residence_country"]=>
  string(2) "US"
  ["item_name"]=>
  string(9) "something"
  ["item_number"]=>
  string(7) "AK-1234"
  ["quantity"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["shipping"]=>
  string(4) "3.04"
  ["tax"]=>
  string(4) "2.02"
  ["mc_currency"]=>
  string(3) "USD"
  ["mc_fee"]=>
  string(4) "0.44"
  ["mc_gross"]=>
  string(5) "12.34"
  ["mc_gross_1"]=>
  string(4) "9.34"
  ["txn_type"]=>
  string(10) "web_accept"
  ["txn_id"]=>
  string(8) "32214658"
  ["notify_version"]=>
  string(3) "2.1"
  ["custom"]=>
  string(6) "xyz123"
  ["charset"]=>
  string(12) "windows-1252"
  ["verify_sign"]=>
  string(56) "A2O3KRKURYa65AG.dmp.MoIqMpDwAmL2IgMH3fAcOss.ur6ERwozl2ty"
}
```

And here is the data from my transactions on a sandbox account:

```
  ["transaction%5B0%5D.is_primary_receiver"]=>
  string(4) "true"
  ["transaction%5B0%5D.id_for_sender_txn"]=>
  string(17) "5SF603183Y786454Y"
  ["log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction"]=>
  string(5) "false"
  ["transaction%5B0%5D.receiver"]=>
  string(37) "sell1_1360732717_biz@derp.com.au"
  ["action_type"]=>
  string(3) "PAY"
  ["ipn_notification_url"]=>
  string(45) "http://portal.derp.com.au/ipn.php"
  ["transaction%5B1%5D.paymentType"]=>
  string(7) "SERVICE"
  ["transaction%5B0%5D.amount"]=>
  string(10) "AUD 199.00"
  ["charset"]=>
  string(12) "windows-1252"
  ["transaction_type"]=>
  string(20) "Adaptive Payment PAY"
  ["transaction%5B1%5D.id_for_sender_txn"]=>
  string(17) "60334361SH094251D"
  ["transaction%5B1%5D.is_primary_receiver"]=>
  string(5) "false"
  ["transaction%5B0%5D.status"]=>
  string(9) "Completed"
  ["notify_version"]=>
  string(11) "UNVERSIONED"
  ["transaction%5B0%5D.id"]=>
  string(17) "8WL542056F860892D"
  ["cancel_url"]=>
  string(38) "http://portal.derp.com.au/"
  ["transaction%5B1%5D.status_for_sender_txn"]=>
  string(9) "Completed"
  ["transaction%5B1%5D.receiver"]=>
  string(37) "sell2_1360732814_biz@derp.com.au"
  ["verify_sign"]=>
  string(56) "An5ns1Kso7MWUdW4ErQKJJJ4qi4-A-p4knnXsUdoGkBReiFAIhHXAyN9"
  ["sender_email"]=>
  string(36) "buy1_1360732893_per@derp.com.au"
  ["fees_payer"]=>
  string(12) "EACHRECEIVER"
  ["transaction%5B0%5D.status_for_sender_txn"]=>
  string(9) "Completed"
  ["return_url"]=>
  string(53) "http://portal.derp.com.au/?p=paypalreturn"
  ["transaction%5B0%5D.paymentType"]=>
  string(7) "SERVICE"
  ["transaction%5B1%5D.amount"]=>
  string(9) "AUD 10.00"
  ["reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error"]=>
  string(5) "false"
  ["tracking_id"]=>
  string(9) "9ZZVg7JNp"
  ["transaction%5B1%5D.pending_reason"]=>
  string(4) "NONE"
  ["pay_key"]=>
  string(20) "AP-6P166651K3308681V"
  ["transaction%5B1%5D.id"]=>
  string(17) "66117669L4710640J"
  ["transaction%5B0%5D.pending_reason"]=>
  string(4) "NONE"
  ["status"]=>
  string(9) "COMPLETED"
  ["transaction%5B1%5D.status"]=>
  string(9) "Completed"
  ["test_ipn"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["payment_request_date"]=>
  string(28) "Wed Feb 13 22:41:09 PST 2013"
}
```

Comment: I just read that when using adaptive payments the data gets returned in a sub array, so like, transaction[0].amount, transaction[1].amount etc, the variable names still dont match up e.g. txn_id is called transaction_id but i can work this now :P If anyone knows why the variable names are different, i would love to know! :P

Answer (score 0):

You going in the right direction.  It depends on what type of IPN you are trying to simulate.  The IPN simulator has been around for some time, it was around before Adaptive Payments.  So it is not going to generate an IPN POST that would be from an Adaptive Payment.  This may be something that gets implemented down the road, but currently this does not allow you to simulate AP transactions through it.  If you are wanting to test IPN's from adaptive payments you would want to go through the flow and make a payment with your test sandbox buyer account to your test sandbox seller account.  The IPN simulator is returning the variables that you would see with DoDirectPayment API's, Web Accept and etc.